# TypeError: Cannot read property 'useMemo' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native

I am new to react native and i am trying to integrate firebase google login into my application. I am using typescript. I unexpectedly got these errors after trying to run my code on my XCode emulator on the build mode
And i am getting these errors. I also haven't used any useMemo hook

> ERROR  Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer
> (such as React DOM)
>
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to
> debug and fix this problem.
>
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'useMemo' of null, js engine:
> hermes
>
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can
> happen if:
>
> * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if
> Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
>
> * A module failed to load due to an error and
> `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I have tried different stack overflow solutions but none have been able to fix my issue

Here is my index.ts

```
import { AppRegistry} from "react-native";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App"

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Here is my App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from './src/components/LoginScreen';
import SignUpScreen from './src/components/SignUpScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from './src/components/ForgotPassword';
import OtpScreen from './src/components/OtpScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" options={{headerShown: false}} component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" options={{headerShown: false}} component={SignUpScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" options={{headerShown: false}} component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OTP" options={{headerShown: false}} component={OtpScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my Login screen where i am trying to implement my google signIn

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { promptAsync, request, response } from '../firebase/firebase.sign-in.util';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
import {auth} from '../firebase/firebase.util';
const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = () => {
        console.log('Login button pressed');
    };
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(response?.type == "success"){
            const {id_token} = response.params;
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
            signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
        }
    },[response])

    return (
        <LinearGradient
            colors={['#CACACA', '#053C4E']}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Email"
                placeholderTextColor="#f6f6f6"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input2}
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="#f6f6f6"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}>
                <Text style={styles.forgotPassword} >Forgot Password ?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => promptAsync()}>
                <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I went through most stackoverflow solutions and none worked for me